# LiveData stops observing when fragment is destroyed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, observers

I have couple of fragments (lets say A,B and C) replacing each other. In fragment A, there is a recyclerView which should be updated as an observer receives changes in a liveData. But the observer does not receive updates when I move to fragment B because fragment A is already destroyed.
I have changed the the lifeCycle owner from viewLifeCycleOwner to this (fragment) but still the same result.

Here is some snippet of my code:

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
val fragments = listOf(fragmentA(), fragmentB(), fragmentC())

private fun moveToFragment(index: Int) {
    if (fragments.isNotEmpty()) {
        viewModel.selectedPage = index
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragments[index])
        transaction.commit()
    }
  }
}

class FragmentA(): Fragment{
     override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        fragmentAViewModel.listOfThings.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { things ->
        things?.let {
            when (things.status) {
                Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    thingsAdapter.submitList(things.data)
                }
                else -> {
                    thingsAdapter.submitList(emptyList())
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

I know that "replace" destroys the fragments but I also tried using HIDE/SHOW fragments but this pattern overlays fragments on top of each other and I wasn't able to get it fixed.

**My question** is what the best practice is here to make sure that the observer/recyclerView is already updated before going to the fragment. Otherwise the recyclerView will have old values and they change in few milliseconds after I go the fragmentA. The most obvious situation is when the recyclerView is supposed to be empty but when I go to fragmentA items are still there for a moment before they disappear.

Comment: by moving this to the containing activity ? all of this sounds like expected behavior if i understand you correctly

Comment: I didn't understand the first part of your comment but about the second part: yes, maybe it is expected behaviour but how I should get the behaviour I want... I don't want the recyclerView to be updated when I go back to fragmentA!

Comment: well regarding `to make sure that the observer/recyclerView is already updated before going to the fragment`, you're really just trying to update the value that the live data has, right ? so why can you not move the viewmodel over the activity so that it has the most relevant data regardless of which fragment it is being used on, aka, a shared viewmodel, which will then use the lifecycle of the activity to survive

Comment: Well, the LiveData has the correct and latest values, and is stored in a repository which has a lifeCycle of application. The issue is that fragmentA is destroyed before the recyclerView being updated. And when it is destroyed an instance is saved which will be loaded when I go back to fragmentA. This way the recyclerView still has the old values.

Comment: What should happen is that when you go back to fragmentA, the values in the `fragmentAViewModel` should be loaded into your recyclerview. If it doesn't, add some logs in your code to see if the lambda is triggered, if the `fragmentAViewModel` has the expected values ...